# get the name andthe of a ressource from the outputs module (example)

Tags: terraform

So i have this structure with conf :

```
module--storage_account_azfiles----main.tf----variables.tf----outputs.tf 

output file_shares {
  description = " Map of Storage SMB file shares. "
  value       = { for f in azurerm_storage_share.fileshare : f.name => f.id }
}
```

In my product folder, azure-files.tf :

```
module "azure_files" {
  source  =    ../modules/storage_account_azfiles 
  storage_account_name                       = ""
  account_tier                               =  "Premium" 
  account_replication_type                   =  "LRS"        
file_shares = [
    { name =  "mfqshare" , quota = 100 }
  ]}
```

i want to get the name of file_shares  mfqshare  from the outputs to use it with this argument :

```
source_file_share_name    = module.azure_files.????????
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `source_file_share_name    = module.azure_files.file_shares["mfqshare"]`?

Comment: i want to get the "mfqshare" directly from the module of the storage account
  
# SMB file share with quota (GB) to create
  file_shares = [
    { name = "mfqshare", quota = 100 }
  ]

Comment: I don't think you can do that with modules.